# Cannot read property 'PeopleManager' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app, user-profile-property

I'm trying to use React `useEffect` Hook to get the current user's profile picture URL. I tried `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` and `executeFunc()` to get the `SP.UserProfiles.js` before running my code. Neither of them worked.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(handleEffect, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
const peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);
```

Is there any other way I can load `SP.UserProfiles.js`?

Answer (score 0):

When we were at SharePoint on-premise, we tend to look at SP.UserProfile.js to load user profile information. When we're on Office 365 world, Graph API is the best source to look at.

You can try on Microsoft Graph API Explorer: [Graph API Explorer - My Photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fphoto%2F%24value&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com). Get the user profile photo (based on example) to the URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

To execute it in your code, get the reference to the MSGraphClient

```
import { MSGraphClient } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
```

If you're using React framework, make sure you pass your WebPartContext to the component. Then you can call it as follows.

```
this.props.webpart.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then((client: MSGraphClient) => {
    client
    .api(`/me/photo/$value`)
    .get((error, response:any, rawResponse: any) => {
        if (rawResponse.ok) {
            //your code here
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**Why Graph API**: Office 365 as the parent bundle product of SharePoint Online does not store the user profile photo on SharePoint User Profile database. Currently, it is being stored on Exchange Online and I am not too sure how it will be in the future. Office 365 is evolving.